# Delete rows in which values are below threshold across all columns

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataframe consisting of 15,000 rows and 350 columns (1 column containing strings, the rest all numbers) in which I'd like to remove rows that contain numbers below a certain number across all integer columns.

Example data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
 ID = c("Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3", "Gene4", "Gene5"),
              var1 = c(245, 2, 0.4, 34,1098),
              var2 = c(908, 1, 54, 34,856),
              var3 = c(0, 3, 650, 0,6)
)

threshold <- 3
> df1
 ID   var1 var2 var3
1 Gene1  245.0  908    0
2 Gene2    2.0    1    3
3 Gene3    0.4   54  650
4 Gene4   34.0   34    0
5 Gene5 1098.0  856    6
```

Desired output:

```
> df1
     ID   var1 var2 var3
1 Gene1  245.0  908    0
3 Gene3    0.4   54  650
4 Gene4   34.0   34    0
5 Gene5 1098.0  856    6
```

Gene2 (which contained numbers below 3 across all columns), has disappeared. How can I achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: `df1[rowSums(df1[-1]<=3)!=ncol(df1[-1]), ]` or even `subset(df1, rowSums(df1[-1]<=3)!=ncol(df1[-1]))`

Comment: Thanks, but this is calculating the sums of these rows. If a row has values 1,0,2,2 - I would still want to remove that row completely, even though the sum is greater than 3. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Please look at the code again. It is not summing the rows but rather ii is removing the rows whereby all the values in that row would be less than 3. If it was summing the rows then `1+2+3=6` and not 3. the code is summing the TRUE, FALSE values generated by `df[-1]<=3` nd not the individual values. This here is the correct code

Comment: Got it, totally my fault. This is actually very concise code, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
> library(dplyr)

> df1 %>% filter_all(any_vars(is.numeric(.) & . > 3))

     ID   var1 var2 var3
1 Gene1  245.0  908    0
2 Gene3    0.4   54  650
3 Gene4   34.0   34    0
4 Gene5 1098.0  856    6
```

Answer (score 1):

A `tidyverse` approach would be next (But @Onyambu is pretty optimal):

```
library(tidyverse)

#Data
df1 <- data.frame(
  ID = c("Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3", "Gene4", "Gene5"),
  var1 = c(245, 2, 0.4, 34,1098),
  var2 = c(908, 1, 54, 34,856),
  var3 = c(0, 3, 650, 0,6)
)

threshold <- 3

#Code
df1 %>% pivot_longer(-ID) %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Flag=sum(value<=3)) %>%
  filter(Flag!=3) %>% select(-c(Flag)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from=value)
```

The output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   ID [4]
  ID      var1  var2  var3
  <fct>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Gene1  245     908     0
2 Gene3    0.4    54   650
3 Gene4   34      34     0
4 Gene5 1098     856     6
```

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear, but I think this is summing a rows values across all columns.  If a row has values 1,0,2,2 - I would still want to remove that row completely, even though the sum is greater than 3. I did learn a few useful functions though, thank you!

Comment: @Workhorse Nice you learnt some functions, with the tidy output I think you could be able to do what you wish :) If in anyway you find this answer useful you could upvote it!!